# ¿Cómo crear eventos en un plugin para jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola estoy creando un plugin para jquery y necesito crear eventos personalizados, por ejemplo que a un input cuando tenga n cantidad de caracteres me lanze un evento   como ha alcanzado el límite máximo, alguien me podría ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos pues con jquery para contabilidar los caracteres y establecer limites podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
<input type="text" id="input_test" onkeyup="validar();">


<script>
function validar(){
max_input = 5;
var valor_input = $("#input_test").val();
total_caracteres = valor_input.length;
if(total_caracteres > max_input){
    alert('Caracteres exceden el limite !!');
  $("#input_test").val(null);
}
}
</script>
```

uso el evento keyup donde invoco a una función que valida y contabiliza los caracteres si se excede el limite muestra una alerta y asu vez establece en null el input respectivo, es algo básico, pero considero que esta bien para empezar y agregar mas utilidades.

Espero te sirva

Comment: tambien podrias revisar esto: https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias es similar a lo que necesito, si no es abusar ¿sabrás cómo agregar este evento a un plugin en jquery?, disculpa si no me supe explicar de la manera correcta